# How to set bootstrap carousel caption color to none?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please let me know how I can set bootstrap carousel caption color to none? I already did this by following code but it didn't work

```
.carosel-caption{ background-color: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misspelled the class; it should instead be `.carousel-caption` - you also can't use `none` as a value for the `background-color` property, though it's valid in the `background` shorthand and in `background-image`, so instead try:

```
.carousel-caption {
    background: none !important;
}
```